# Django Many to Many field dependent on another many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating two many-to-many fields based on same model in a single model. I would like to show only those instances in second many-to-many field which are selected in first many to many field to further apply selection. Through which approach should i handle this behaviour.

```
class Params(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    comments = Model.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
           return self.name

class Selection(models.Model):
    select_params = models.ManyToManyField(Params, blank=True, related_name = "selection_1")
    edit_selected_params = models.ManyToManyField(Params, blank=True, related_name = 
            "selection_from_selec_params")
```

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SubQuery` is think:

```py
selected = Selection.objects.filter(
    edit_selected_params__in=SubQuery(
        Selection.objects.filter(select_params__isnull=False).values_list("select_params", flat=True)
    )
)
```

You can see [SubQuery docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. will it be in models or to access from views. I'm looking to access the selected instances of many to many field to further select the specific ones to display or not to display after selection. as open choice to user from admin panel

Comment: You can use it in your view. I hope it gives you what you want. @Kashan

Comment: should i create a child class and add the edit_selected_params field in child class which many to many field will have the instances from select params

Comment: unfortunately no I give the access to user with 2 many to many fields in admin panel and he selects the items in one many to many field and the instances of that many to many field in another many to many field to further select more. hope I could be able to explain the problem. thanks